# Port 8080 already in use in eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, apache

I am trying to run a Spring MVC demo file on **Eclipse oxygen** when I hit the button run as> run on server it shows the following error after a moment

> Port 8080 required by Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)

Answer (score 8):

> Step 1: (open the CMD command)

```
  C:\Users\username>netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:8080

  TCP 0.0.0.0:3000 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 3116

  Now , we can see that LISTENING port is 3116 for 8080 ,

  We need to kill 3116 now
```

> Step 2:-

```
 C:\Users\username>taskkill /F /PID 3116

 Step 3: Go to Eclipse and start Server , it will run
```

> OR

```
 you can change port number in folder  servers>Tomcat>server.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

A process is already listening on port **8080** and you can't have more than one process listening on the same port.

You have **two options** :

1. Kill the existing process if it's not usefull 
   `netstat -tulpn | grep :8080`
2. Change you application port. In your application.properties and file add this line `server.port=8081`

Comment: how to know whether the process is useful or which process is running

Comment: if you can browse localhost:8080 that means the port is already in use.

Comment: Depends of your OS. On linux, just use the command line I gave you above. Get the PID of the process and kill it with `kill -9 ${PID}`

Comment: @Shrikant Not necessarily. A process can be running on a port without listening on HTTP

Answer (score 0):

in your apache conf folder, open the httpd file and look for 8080 port. Change 8080 to any port you like. I believe you will find 8080 on two places

Answer (score 0):

please kill the java process from task manager if windows, else if linux system kill -9 tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the default port of your Tomcat server if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Always Kill the process before deploying your war file in tomcat

`ps -A|grep tomcat` It will list all tomcat process. Note Down the PID and run

`KILL <PID>`

Cross check by `ps -A|grep tomcat`

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem and after searching the answer as shown below:
1. open Monitor Tomcat as shown below:

[image]

2. Simply press stop as shown in below picture:

[image]

Finally it works with me after many trials and suggested solutions.

Best Regards,
Kerelos Mikhail

Answer (score 0):

My method is to run tomcat7w.exe  to disable it. (Only Stopping  it is not enough). And my Kaspersky (Anti virus) generate some new rules for eclipse and java.

Answer (score 0):

Followed below steps and was able to solve the issue:

C:\Users\Sri Priya P Kulkarni>netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:8080
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       13196

C:\Users\Sri Priya P Kulkarni>taskkill /F /PID 13196
SUCCESS: The process with PID 13196 has been terminated.

Answer (score -1):

you can go in **servers > server.xml**.in server.xml file u should changes like,
step 1)  
step 2)  
step 3) <**Connector port="8010"** protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/> and save the changes .